# qt QScatterSeries clicked signal is emitted to ChartView mousePressEvent

Tags: qt, mouseevent, signals-slots, qchar

I have a custom implementation of QChartView where I can zoom. (Class "**ChartView**" from [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-zoomlinechart-example.html) example) 
In there I have a **mousePressEvent**.

Now I wanted to add a QScatterSeries and connect the **clicked** signal with a custom slot. Unfortunately as soon as I click on my QScatterSeries only a signal is emitted to my **ChartView mousePressEvent** slot and not to my **QScatterSeries mypoint_clicked** slot.

I also added an **QScatterSeries hovered** signal which works fine.

```
connect(myScatterSeries, SIGNAL(hovered(QPointF,bool)), this, SLOT(mypoint_hovered(QPointF,bool)));
connect(myScatterSeries, SIGNAL(clicked(QPointF)), this, SLOT(mypoint_clicked(QPointF)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing here.

`mousePressEvent()` is not a slot, but an event handler. I guess that `QChartView::mousePressEvent()` is somewhat responsible for handling mouse press events on the chart and dispatching them to series.

If you reimplemented `ChartView::mousePressEvent()` without explicitly calling `QChartView::mousePressEvent()` to forward the event, you might prevent the normal event processing to dispatch the event to the series. And therefore `QScatterSeries::clicked()` is never emitted.

Comment: I call `QChartView::mousePressEvent(event);` in my `void ChartView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` function...

Comment: @user7431005 Ok. Can you provide more details and more samples of your code like your class definitions and implementations of interesting functions like `mousePressEvent()`?

Comment: it is the same as in [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-zoomlinechart-example.html) example, class ChartView

Comment: @user7431005 Have you tried running the example ? If the example works and not your code then you need to show your code (or a minimal working example that reproduce the error) if you want people to help you. If the example does not work, then it is not your code.